# not defined js variable problem with laravel mix

Tags: laravel, npm

I using WOW animate library for set animations to elements on website load, these are my codes in resources/js/scripts.js

```
require('./files/jquery3.3');
require('./files/effect');
require('./files/wow.min'); //wow library 
require('./files/search_page');
```

in wepack.mix.js I use this code for mix this file

```
mix.js('resources/js/script.js', 'public/js')
```

and in my blade file at the end of the footer of file, I use these codes

```
<script src="/js/innerPages.js"></script>
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

and browser console give me this error 
'Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined'

Comment: You tag this with `npm`, but then have a `script` tag and talk about browser console. Are you running this in node or at client side?

Comment: @trincot I use npm tag because laravel mix is in npm and will install by this command 'npm install'

Comment: In a browser context shouldn't you be using `import` instead of `require()`? Or are you using something like requireJS?

Comment: @trincot we use import for css files , for javascript we must use require() in laravel mix

Comment: I think you need to write `<script src="./files/wow.min.js"></script>`. Not sure whether it is supposed to work with `require()`.